# Why do specific returned lambda types result in ambiguity

Tags: kotlin

In the following example, I don't understand what is ambiguous about the function.

```
fun <P1, R> test(init : () -> (P1) -> R) {

}


fun <P1, P2, R> test(init : () -> (P1, P2) -> R) {

}

fun main() {
    test {
        fun (p1 : Long) {

        }
    }
}
```

For some reason it can't figure out which test to call, even though the returned anonymous function clearly takes a single parameter. What am I misunderstanding about the semantics here?

Comment: It might be this compiler bug. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30241/Inference-error-for-postponed-arguments-when-there-are-more-than-one-candidates-with-different-return-functional-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of JVM. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Let's check at first this example:

```kotlin
fun <P1, R> test(init: () -> (P1) -> R) {
}

fun <P1, P2, R> test(init: () -> (P1, P2) -> R) {
}

fun main() {
    val test1 = test<String, Unit> {
        {
            println("test: $it")
        }
    }

    val test2 = test<String, String, Unit> {
        { p1: String, p2: String ->
            println("test: $p1-$p2")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Will the code compile? Surprise surprise, even with the types declared, the compilation will fail with message:

```
Kotlin: Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (test(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V):
    fun <P1, R> test(init: () -> (P1) -> R): Unit defined in com.example.springsandbox
    fun <P1, P2, R> test(init: () -> (P1, P2) -> R): Unit defined in com.example.springsandbox
```

This message tells us a lot, where there can be a problem.  We can easily fix it by changing JVM signature:

```
@JvmName("test1")
fun <P1, R> test(init: () -> (P1) -> R) {
}

@JvmName("test2")
fun <P1, P2, R> test(init: () -> (P1, P2) -> R) {

}
```

Now, our code will compile, but we still need to add types when invoking the `test` function. So let's check what is going on down there.

```
public final class com/example/springsandbox/NotepadKt {


  // access flags 0x19
  // signature <P1:Ljava/lang/Object;R:Ljava/lang/Object;>(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0<+Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1<-TP1;+TR;>;>;)V
  // declaration: void test1<P1, R>(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<? extends kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super P1, ? extends R>>)
  public final static test1(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V
  @Lkotlin/jvm/JvmName;(name="test1") // invisible
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 0
    LDC "init"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 6 L2
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE init Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0; L0 L3 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x19
  // signature <P1:Ljava/lang/Object;P2:Ljava/lang/Object;R:Ljava/lang/Object;>(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0<+Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2<-TP1;-TP2;+TR;>;>;)V
  // declaration: void test2<P1, P2, R>(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<? extends kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2<? super P1, ? super P2, ? extends R>>)
  public final static test2(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V
  @Lkotlin/jvm/JvmName;(name="test2") // invisible
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 0
    LDC "init"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 11 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE init Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // compiled from: notepad.kt
}
```

Test-fun accessors in the bytecode looks the following:

```
   L0
    LINENUMBER 14 L0
    GETSTATIC com/example/springsandbox/NotepadKt$main$test1$1.INSTANCE : Lcom/example/springsandbox/NotepadKt$main$test1$1;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function0
    INVOKESTATIC com/example/springsandbox/NotepadKt.test1 (Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V
    GETSTATIC kotlin/Unit.INSTANCE : Lkotlin/Unit;
    ASTORE 0
   L1
    LINENUMBER 20 L1
    GETSTATIC com/example/springsandbox/NotepadKt$main$test2$1.INSTANCE : Lcom/example/springsandbox/NotepadKt$main$test2$1;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function0
    INVOKESTATIC com/example/springsandbox/NotepadKt.test2 (Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V
    GETSTATIC kotlin/Unit.INSTANCE : Lkotlin/Unit;
    ASTORE 1
```

Both test functions have (almost) the same signature: `Function0` (the only difference is the function name, which has been changed by `@JvmName` annotation). The generic type is not here because JVM has erased it ;)

We can decompile the working code as well to see the clash:

```
public final class NotepadKt {
   @JvmName(
      name = "test1"
   )
   public static final void test1(@NotNull Function0 init) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(init, "init");
   }

   @JvmName(
      name = "test2"
   )
   public static final void test2(@NotNull Function0 init) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(init, "init");
   }

   public static final void main() {
      test1((Function0)null.INSTANCE);
      Unit test1 = Unit.INSTANCE;
      test2((Function0)null.INSTANCE);
      Unit test2 = Unit.INSTANCE;
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static void main(String[] var0) {
      main();
   }
}
```

And this show us clearly where there is a problem - both declared functions takes the same parameter, so we need to help the Kotlin Compiler which one to choose.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

So, I am not sure if this can be considered as a bug, or more as a JVM limitation (or, in fact, if we take under the consideration types inheritance (I mean `T: () -> Any, S: () -> () -> Any; S is a subtype of T`) the answer may not be so obvious).

Comment: Damn this a great answer, but that is a very annoying shortcoming. Thanks for the deep dive on this sir!